# Wildcard query in PHP renders in SQL not in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, wildcard

I've been fiddling with this query in PHP for a day or two now. I'm using PHP 5.4 MySQL 5.6. The query below works fine in SQL, but doesn't work in PHP. I've googled for an answer and searched stack overflow for wildcard answers in PHP and SQL. It really is quite a thorn in my side at the moment as to why it is not working.

```
$search_string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", " ", $_POST['query']);
$search_string = mysql_real_escape_string($search_string);

$query = 'SELECT * FROM population WHERE location LIKE "'.$search_string.'%"';
```

Let me know if you need anymore information - I'm using phpmyadmin for SQL if that helps.

Thanks

Edit: I'm trying to wildcard search from a database of cities so the first 2 characters typed 'Al' should produce an autocomplete with all cities starting with 'Al'.

If I include both a wildcard in the front %'.$search_string.'%"'; it will autocomplete as expected (finding all matching characters where ever they might be in the string), but if I remove the first % it returns "no results."

Update:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM population WHERE location LIKE "%'.$search_string.'"';
```

returns all city names starting with the last characters.

An example: typing '**Al**' returns "centr**al**, norm**al**, etc." but again if I put my wildcard in the back its as though PHP is not parsing the query.

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? Does it error out? What kind of value is $search_string set to?

Comment: Hi there.  **What is the desired behaviour?**  Also, **can you show us what that query is doing?**  If it's throwing an error, then what is the error?  Or if it's doing something, just not what you want, can you show us the bad output?

Answer (score 0):

So, just curious and hard to answer without more information but have you tried:

> WHERE LOWER(location) LIKE LOWER('".$string."%')

Give me more information about the type of string that might get passed through that query... I believe it may be working with the additional wildcard due to location being stored in proper case and the string being lower or upper...